# How should I change <div id="root"></div> of CreateReactApp to increase Web Accessibility?

Tags: html, reactjs, accessibility, create-react-app, wai-aria

When creating a React App with [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app), it generates the `public/index.html` file as follows:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- <meta>, <link>, <title> here -->
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div> <!-- Can this be made more accessible? -->
  </body>
</html>
```

The line `<div id="root"></div>` passes the validation of eslint `jsx-a11y/strict` plugin, but a [VSCode Web Accessibility plugin](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MaxvanderSchee.web-accessibility) suggests replacing `<div>` with a [Semantic HTML](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_semantic_elements.asp), or assigning a [WAI-ARIA role](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Roles) attribute to it (Btw, Lighthouse also has a flags the original setup for not including a [landmark region, heading or skiplink](https://web.dev/bypass/?utm_source=lighthouse&utm_medium=devtools)).

In short, I wonder if I should modify `<div id="root"></div>` line in this file for the sake of accessibility. If yes, which Semantic HTML tag or role should I use?

Comment: lighthouse shouldn't flag your application, this is probably an unrelated issue to the root div issue in your question as lighthouse checks the rendered page. Do you have a public URL so I can help you with that part? Quentin's answer is correct as far as the container, that can be left as a div, it will have no impact on accessibility assuming the rest of your application is using semantic elements correctly.

Comment: @GrahamRitchie Although it is not fully operational, https://tafalk.com/ is where I run Lighthouse reports on and get the audit as `The page does not contain a heading, skip link, or landmark region` with detail `Failing elements: html`. And if helps, the source code is at: https://github.com/tafalk/tafalk-web

Comment: Yes so that is a separate issue, you need a skip link (https://webaim.org/techniques/skipnav/) and you need to implement landmark regions at the top level such as header (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/header), main (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/main) and footer ( https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/footer) etc. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element "Content Sectioning" heading. These must be top level (so direct children of your `<div="root">`.

Comment: @GrahamRitchie Thank you very much, applying a [skiplink](https://web.dev/headings-and-landmarks/#bypass-repetitive-content-with-skip-links) and `main` landmark was the real deal; no need to change generated code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't change it. Remember that automated testing tools are *dumb*. They can see that you have a div and guess that it should be something with semantic meaning, but they can't be sure.

Presumably, the React code will populate that div with semantic elements (such as `nav` and `main`). That will provide the semantic needs for accessibility.

Note that the VS Code extension you link to appears to be designed to test static HTML. It isn't going to be useful for a page generated with client-side JS.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change the `div` tag to the `main` tag in the `index.html` file like this

```
<main id="root"></main>
```

and then you can run google lighthouse test and see the accessibility metric

Answer (score 0):

To expand upon the previous answer and for clarification: In my case, I had not used a 'main' tag at all.

My application was using a styled div as AppContainer, between the TopNav and Footer components.

```
<Router>
    <TopNav />
    <SideBar />
    <AppContainer>
        <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={HomePage} />
        </Switch>
    </AppContainer>
    <Footer />
</Router>
```

I simply had to change

```
const AppContainer = styled.div`[...]`
```

to

```
const AppContainer = styled.main`[...]`
```